# hylafax not sending fax using iaxmodem

Tags: asterisk, modem, fax

Hi everyone i am having an issue with Hylafax + iaxmodem + asterisk/freepbx. It is odd because i can receive faxes correctly and don't have any issues, but when i try to send a fax using hylafax it just says no answer from remote and when i am looking at asterisk by doing asterisk -r i don't even see the iaxmodem trying to send out a fax. I am lost at this point. I can successfully receive but cannot send and the iaxmodem extension is registered in asterisk. I am not sure what type of configuration files you need to see to try and help me, but if you ask for the files i can provide them. Thanks!

Comment: If you installed hylafax correctly, it work ok. Very likly you missed create outbound context.

Comment: @arheops but i don't see anything in the asterisk console when it try to send out. Usually with Asterisk whether it's inbound call or outbound you see some traffic in the console, but i get nothing on outbound calls, but on inbound calls it works and i see the traffic that asterisk connects to iaxmodem.

Comment: There are 2 ways send out calls 1) via call files 2) via manager api. I am unsure which one use Hylafax, but very likly you not setup any. Sure if no context exit or no way create call you will see nothing. Please do again setup of hylafax, pay attention to context/outbound call creation.

Comment: I still cannot send out faxes. ONly receive faxes i have build iaxmodem and hylafax from source on the local freepbx box. Same result i can receive fax but i cannot send fax out. No activity on the asterisk cli when attempting to send out a fax. All i have is no answer from remote. @arheops can you tell me where in hylafax do i configure what context to use? I'm using from-internal in my extensions for iaxmodem. went through hylafax setup step by step and did not see anything of call files or context. thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, no way predict what exactly  you did wrong. Please consult this page: http://www.hylafax.org/content/Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the solution was to my issue. The password i was using for the iax extension had an '@' symbol in it. This caused the whole issue. I removed it and faxing started to work accordingly. I stumbled upon this in this german forum that i had to translate to english.

http://www.ip-phone-forum.de/showthread.php?t=254880

Thank you everyone for all the help.